# VBA highlight cell that is not a date in a range

Tags: vba, date, highlight

I am trying to highlight the non date value in a range. However my code  somehow get me to highlight the blank cell ,
could please advise what should i change?

```
 Sub colortest()
 Set MyPage = Range("B2:D6")
 For Each cell In MyPage
 Select Case cell.Value
 Case Not IsDate(cell) = False
 cell.Interior.Color = 65535
 Case Is = "abc"
 cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
 End Select
 Next
 End Sub
```

�

#### Excel screen shot

[image: Excel screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub colortest()
    Dim MyPlage As Range, currentCell As Range
    Set MyPlage = Range("B2:D6")

    For Each currentCell In MyPlage
        If Not IsEmpty(currentCell) Then
            Select Case IsDate(currentCell.Value)
            Case 1
                currentCell.Interior.Color = 65535
            Case 0
                currentCell.Interior.Color = 15
            End Select
        End If
    Next currentCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SpecialCells()` method to loop through "constant" (i.e. skipping blanks) cells

```
Dim MyPlage As Range, cell As Range

Set MyPlage = Range("B2:D6")
For Each cell In MyPlage.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case Not IsDate(cell) = False
            cell.Interior.Color = 65535
        Case Is = "abc"
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End Select
Next
```

while if your data in `MyPlage` range has formulas, you just change `xlCellTypeConstants` to `xlCellTypeFormulas`